# How do I override bootstrap's mark style?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I've read a bunch of articles on this but it's still not working. I'm just trying to remove the padding that bootstrap adds around the mark tag, since I'm changing highlights as the user types and its jarring to see the text move around when you type.

Here is my App.css

```
mark .query{
  padding: 0em;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Here is the actual React code (I'm using Highlighter, which generates a \ tag).

```
<Highlighter
                highlightClassName="query"
                searchWords={[this.props.query]}
                autoEscape={true}
                textToHighlight={result}/>
```

Here is the HTML rendered by React

```
<mark class="query ">Text</mark>
```

Here is my css import

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';
```

And here is the computed style

[image: Computed Style]

So frustrating!! :)

Comment: `mark.query`, not `mark .query` - You're not targeting the Element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're targeting the wrong Element

This is finding a `<mark>`, and then selecting the descendant Element with the `query` class

```
mark .query { ... }
```

You want to find a `<mark>`, which has also has a `query` class, so join them together

```
mark.query { ... }
```

Comment: @whenitrains Also, if this answer has helped you, could you mark it as accepted - This will reward both you and I with some reputation, and will mark your question as solved. [How does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I tried immediately after you answered, but it said I "had to wait 11 minutes", which seems strange. I guess to let others try their hand??

Comment: Yeah - Sorry for being impatient. There's a 15 minute timer before you can accept an answer; Thank you though